# The event won't trigger when I use a variable for a selector

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>RECEIPT</h1>

    <datalist id="codes">
    <?php
    require_once('../../../mysqli_connect.php');
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT itemcode FROM itemcost";
    $response = @mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)){
        echo    '<option value="' . $row['itemcode'] . '">';
                                                }       
    ?>
    </datalist>

<form action="receipt.php" method="POST">

    <table cellspacing="10" id="tbl">
    <thead>
        <td>ITEM CODE:</td>
        <td>ITEM NAME: </td>
        <td>QUANTITY OF ITEM:</td>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" list="codes" name="Item_Code1" id="setter" size="5" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Item_Name1" id="receiver" size="10"  /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Quantity_In1" size="5" /></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="number" name="rows" id="addrows" />
    <button type="button" id="btn">Add More</button>
    <input type="submit" name="submitted" value="Enter" />
    <input type="text" name="sendtotalrows" id="totalrows" style="visibility:hidden"/>


</form>

<script src="jquery.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function(){

    window.rowcompare = 2;  
    window.previousrownumber = 1;

    $('#setter').change(function(){ $.getJSON('getitemcodename.php', function(itemcodename) {
                                        var selectedItemCode = $('#setter').val();
                                        $('#receiver').val(itemcodename[selectedItemCode]);});});

    $('#btn').on('click', function(){
        var rownumber = $('#addrows').val();
        rownumber = parseInt(rownumber) + window.previousrownumber;

        while( rownumber >= rowcompare){
        $('#tbl').find('tbody').append("<tr><td><input type=\"text\" list=\"codes\" name=\"Item_Code" + rowcompare +"\" id=\"setter" + rowcompare +"\" size=\"5\" /></td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"Item_Name" + rowcompare +"\" id=\"receiver" + rowcompare +"\" size=\"10\"  /></td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"Quantity_In" + rowcompare +"\" size=\"5\" /></td></tr>");

        $("#setter" + rowcompare).change(function(){ $.getJSON('getitemcodename.php', function(itemcodename) {
                                                    var selectedItemCode = $("#setter" + rowcompare).val();
                                                        $("#receiver" + rowcompare).val(itemcodename[selectedItemCode]);});});                      
        rowcompare++;
        }
        previousrownumber = rownumber;
        $('#totalrows').val(previousrownumber);
    });

    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

My problem lies in this part of the code inside the while loop where I try to concatenate a variable to the Selector.

getitemcode.php just returns a key-value pair

```
$("#setter" + rowcompare).change(function(){ $.getJSON('getitemcodename.php', function(itemcodename) {
                                                    var selectedItemCode = $("#setter" + rowcompare).val();
                                                        $("#receiver" + rowcompare).val(itemcodename[selectedItemCode]);
});
});
```

As the title says, my event won't trigger. I've seen similar questions asked and below are the answers I've tried:

```
var IcodeID = 'setter' + toString(rowcompare)
var InameID = 'receiver' + toString(rowcompare)

$("#" + IcodeID ).change(function(){ $.getJSON('getitemcodename.php', function(itemcodename) {
                                                    var selectedItemCode = $("#" + IcodeID ).val();
                                                        $("#" + InameID ).val(itemcodename[selectedItemCode]);
});
});
parseInt(rowcompare);
```

```
$("#setter" + ${rowcompare}).change(function(){ $.getJSON('getitemcodename.php', function(itemcodename) {
                                                    var selectedItemCode = $("#setter" + ${rowcompare}).val();
                                                        $("#receiver" + ${rowcompare}).val(itemcodename[selectedItemCode]);
});
});
```

```
parseInt(rowcompare);
$("#setter" + rowcompare).change(function(){ $.getJSON('getitemcodename.php', function(itemcodename) {
                                                    var selectedItemCode = $("#setter" + rowcompare).val();
                                                        $("#receiver" + rowcompare).val(itemcodename[selectedItemCode]);
});
});
```

But the thing is when I try this:

```
$("#setter" + 2).change(function(){ $.getJSON('getitemcodename.php', function(itemcodename) {
                                                    var selectedItemCode = $("#setter" + 2).val();
                                                        $("#receiver" + 2).val(itemcodename[selectedItemCode]);
});
});
```

It works. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might consider using consistent indentation when writing code - it'll make reading and debugging it much easier, not only for potential answerers, but for you as well, when we can all see the `{` `}` blocks and their nesting level at a glance, rather than having to carefully pick through each line just to pick up on the logical paths.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution from this link:

[Passing variable to :eq jquery selector in a while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975902/passing-variable-to-eq-jquery-selector-in-a-while-loop)

You need to wrap the Jquery code that uses the incremented variable inside this:

(function(rowcompare){ Jquery Code })(rowcompare);

Like so:

```
(function(rowcompare){
            $(".code-input" + rowcompare).change(function(){ $.getJSON('getitemcodename.php', function(itemcodenamestocks) {
                                                         var selectedItemCode = $(".code-input" + rowcompare).val();                            
                                                         $(".code-output" + rowcompare).val(itemcodenamestocks[0][selectedItemCode]);
                                                         $(".stocks-output" + rowcompare).val(itemcodenamestocks[1][selectedItemCode]);
            });
            });
            })(rowcompare);
```

And it works.